# Copy Data from Other sheet to current open Sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy data from one excel to another and then refreshing all the pivot tables in open sheet. facing issue here that below Macro telling me to open the sheet always where i need to copy my data. please help me as i dont want to open again my second file.

```
Sub UReport()
'
' UReport Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+T
'
    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook

'## Open both workbooks first:
    Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Reports\HC Report.xlsx")
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Reports\Main Tracker.xlsx")

'Now, copy what you want from x:
    x.Sheets("HC Report").Range("A2:FI7004").Copy

'Now, paste to y worksheet:
    y.Sheets("My Data").Range("A2:FI7004").PasteSpecial

    Sheets("Dashboard").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Sheets("My Data").Select

'Close x:
    x.Close
    End Sub
```

Comment: So your problem is: the second spreadsheet may be open in Excel and the macro wants to forcibly open it again?

Comment: problem is not clear. please develop on what you actually need to achieve.

Comment: Is `Sheets("Dashboard")` in x or y?

Comment: What is the error that you get? I tried running your code and its working for me. Could you please provide us more details?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sheets("Dashboard").Select
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Sheets("My Data").Select
```

This is ambiguous. The `ActiveWorkbook` is `y`. If the sheet "Dashboard" doesn't exist in `y` then you will have an error. If it's this problem then use :

```
x.Sheets("Dashboard").Select
```

Just as you did previously with the other sheets !

By the way, if you don't want any screen updating as file opening can be long (and maybe cause errors), use

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = false 'at the beginning of sub
' code here
Application.ScreenUpdating = true ' at the end of sub
```